# Windows Server 2008 Standard upgrade to Windows Server 2008 Enterprise very slow

Tags: windows-server-2008, upgrade

We host a client virtual server that runs Windows Server 2008 Standard Edition x64. They now need to up the memory to 96GB which isn't possible with Standard Edition, so we need to "upgrade" the edition to Enterprise.

We took a clone of the VM and are performing a test to see how long it takes and that it succeeds before the actual upgrade is performed.

Problem is, it's been running for 3 hours and is only at the `Gathering files (15%)` stage.

We told it not to go out to the web, because this VM has restricted Internet access.

Is this normal?

Comment: What's the hypervisor storage? How is the hypervisor resource load? When I've seen this issue it's been due to slow underlying storage.

Comment: We are using an EMC VNX SAN for both storage of the ISO and VM. Raid 5 datastore of 4.7TB SAS drives. Not seeing any issues with performance on the VM or SAN to indicate this is the problem.